# 'GlobalHost' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR'

Tags: vb.net, iis, signalr, ambiguous

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error, I'm using signalr 1.1.3 (I upgraded from 1.0.0 recently) but after upgrading, this error has been plaguing me for a while. Any help is much appreciated.
the file in question

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Xml
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports UserSystem
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Public Class AutopilotHub
Inherits Hub
```

and, I'm using globalhost several times throughout...
e.g. :

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of AutopilotHub).Clients.All.syncTime(index, 0, currentVideo.length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by changing visual studio version, from 2010 to 2012 and removing all references to signalR and reinstalling all components